# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when assigning a NSDecimalNumber to the class property from a function in Objective C

Tags: ios, iphone, properties

iOS App is being crashed in Xcode simulator assigning a NSDecimalNumber to the property of a class, following is the code:

```
CardData *cd = (CardData *)[swipeHQ getContext:contextCardData];
cd.amount   = chargeAmount; // issue here
```

amount is used in the class CardData as instance and property as well with the same name. Property is defined as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDecimalNumber *amount;
```

Following is the Log. (You may have to scroll to the right to see the complete amount of messages)

```
objc[1893]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x1434f44c) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0x14190b78). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1893]: Class PDFScrollView is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PDFKit.framework/PDFKit (0x13350750) and /Users/mycompany/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EDB0ED60-0697-49C5-A1DA-6CF7D3E9550D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7A1827ED-959C-410D-8A81-F9C06A77FF71/MyApp.app/MyApp (0x28a6fc). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2017-08-08 14:10:06.841 MyApp[1893:111440] stopping location updates
2017-08-08 14:10:06.882 MyApp[1893:111440] [Crashlytics] Version 3.8.4 (121)
2017-08-08 14:10:06.999 MyApp[1893:111440] <0x7b75dcf0 MyAppheckoutAppDelegate.m:-[MyAppheckoutAppDelegate updateInterfaceWithReachability:](233)> Internet connection
2017-08-08 14:10:07.003 MyApp[1893:111440] <0x7b75dcf0 MyAppheckoutAppDelegate.m:-[MyAppheckoutAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:](283)> READER IS NOT INSERTED
2017-08-08 14:10:07.022 MyApp[1893:111440] <0x7b75dcf0 MyAppheckoutAppDelegate.m:-[MyAppheckoutAppDelegate copySqliteToApplicationBundle](159)> Database path = /Users/mycompany/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EDB0ED60-0697-49C5-A1DA-6CF7D3E9550D/data/Containers/Data/Application/372BD428-FE37-4C16-8CF7-3813C4144663/Documents/MyApp/MyApp104.ohq
2017-08-08 14:10:07.024 MyApp[1893:111440] <0x7b7f8b00 SqliteDataAccess.m:-[SqliteDataAccess getAunthenticationManager:](242)> secret:ARC+5vweHOHHtSwHNDq4z9q4ssWzjAauoLgazDeS6qGEpCuQoe/hIIzHeh/ro0q5d3kHGpnsH0bbmG/7528TvQ==
2017-08-08 14:10:07.024 MyApp[1893:111440] <0x7b7f8b00 SqliteDataAccess.m:-[SqliteDataAccess getAunthenticationManager:](243)> pinkey:e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
2017-08-08 14:10:07.025 MyApp[1893:111440] <0x7b7f8b00 SqliteDataAccess.m:-[SqliteDataAccess getAunthenticationManager:](244)> merchantid:¢¡ï(û«ÉŽ:4 ÏÓûn
                                                                                                                                                 2017-08-08 14:10:07.026 MyApp[1893:111440] <0x7b7f8b00 SqliteDataAccess.m:-[SqliteDataAccess getAunthenticationManager:](245)>
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:07.026 MyApp[1893:111440] <0x7b7f8b00 SqliteDataAccess.m:-[SqliteDataAccess getAunthenticationManager:](246)> domain:.com
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:07.396 MyApp[1893:111440] Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-NumberPad; using 1925800565_Portrait_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:22.109 MyApp[1893:111440] <0x7b7f8b00 SqliteDataAccess.m:-[SqliteDataAccess getAunthenticationManager:](242)> 
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:22.110 MyApp[1893:111440] <0x7b7f8b00 SqliteDataAccess.m:-[SqliteDataAccess getAunthenticationManager:](243)> 
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:22.110 MyApp[1893:111440] <0x7b7f8b00 SqliteDataAccess.m:-[SqliteDataAccess getAunthenticationManager:](244)> merchantid:79CB1C308E413
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:22.110 MyApp[1893:111440] <0x7b7f8b00 SqliteDataAccess.m:-[SqliteDataAccess getAunthenticationManager:](245)> 
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:22.111 MyApp[1893:111440] <0x7b7f8b00 SqliteDataAccess.m:-[SqliteDataAccess getAunthenticationManager:](246)> domain:.com
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:22.231 MyApp[1893:111440] <0x7cc480a0 MenuController.m:-[MenuController viewDidLoad](91)> local account status = active
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:22.232 MyApp[1893:111440] <0x7cabf540 MyAppAPICall.m:-[MyAppAPICall initWithServer:forApiCall:withParameters:](59)> API call : https://api.MyApp.com/
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:22.232 MyApp[1893:111440] url string = https://api.MyApp.com/
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:22.234 MyApp[1893:111440] <0x7cb492c0 MyAppAPICall.m:-[MyAppAPICall initWithServer:forApiCall:withParameters:](59)> API call : https://api.MyApp.com/
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:22.234 MyApp[1893:111440] url string = https://api.MyApp.com/
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:22.243 MyApp[1893:111440] <0x7ca10930 MyAppAPICall.m:-[MyAppAPICall initWithServer:forApiCall:withParameters:](59)> API call : https://api.MyApp.com/
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:22.243 MyApp[1893:111440] url string = https://api.MyApp.com/
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:22.244 MyApp[1893:111440] <0x7cc47080 MyAppAPICall.m:-[MyAppAPICall initWithServer:forApiCall:withParameters:](59)> API call : https://api.MyApp.com/mode=get_currency_data
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:22.244 MyApp[1893:111440] url string = https://api.MyApp.com/mode=get_currency_data
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:22.245 MyApp[1893:111440] <0x7ca08cb0 MyAppAPICall.m:-[MyAppAPICall initWithServer:forApiCall:withParameters:](59)> API call : https://api.MyApp.com/fetchProductMeta.php
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:22.245 MyApp[1893:111440] url string = https://api.MyApp.com/apikey
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:22.250 MyApp[1893:111440] stopping location updates
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:23.054 MyApp[1893:111440] <0x7cabf540 MyAppAPICall.m:-[MyAppAPICall connectionDidFinishLoading:](139)> {                                                                                                                     }
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:23.063 MyApp[1893:111440] delegate = <MenuViewController: 0x7cc480a0>
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:23.065 MyApp[1893:111440] <0x7cc480a0 MenuController.m:-[MenuController APICall:didReceiveResponse:](278)> menu fetch merchant results = {                                                                                                                                              }
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:23.105 MyApp[1893:111440] <0x28a8f0 MenuController.m:+[MenuController updateTaxSettingsFromResponse:forAppDelegate:](405)> updateTaxSettings called, mcTaxSettings = (null)
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:23.255 MyApp[1893:111440] <0x7ca08cb0 MyAppAPICall.m:-[MyAppAPICall connectionDidFinishLoading:](139)> {
                                                                                                                                                         data =     {                                                                                                                           }
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:23.277 MyApp[1893:111440] delegate = <SynchronizeStorefront: 0x7ca08840>
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:23.458 MyApp[1893:111440] <0x7cb492c0 MyAppAPICall.m:-[MyAppAPICall connectionDidFinishLoading:](139)> {
                                                                                                                                                         data =     {
                                                                                                                                                     }
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:23.458 MyApp[1893:111440] delegate = <SynchronizeStorefront: 0x7cb48810>
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:23.467 MyApp[1893:111440] <0x7b645a70 MyAppAPICall.m:-[MyAppAPICall initWithServer:forApiCall:withParameters:](59)> API call : https://api.MyApp.com/
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:23.467 MyApp[1893:111440] url string = https://api.MyApp.com/
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:23.467 MyApp[1893:111440] <0x7cbb6650 MyAppAPICall.m:-[MyAppAPICall initWithServer:forApiCall:withParameters:](59)> API call : https://api.MyApp.com/mode=get_currency_data
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:23.468 MyApp[1893:111440] url string = https://api.MyApp.com/mode=get_currency_data
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:23.468 MyApp[1893:111440] <0x7cc5cca0 MyAppAPICall.m:-[MyAppAPICall initWithServer:forApiCall:withParameters:](59)> API call : https://api.MyApp.com/
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:23.470 MyApp[1893:111440] url string = https://api.MyApp.com/
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:23.473 MyApp[1893:111440] stopping location updates
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:23.674 MyApp[1893:111440] <0x7cbb6650 MyAppAPICall.m:-[MyAppAPICall connectionDidFinishLoading:](139)> {
                                                                                                                                                         data =     {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                     }
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:23.675 MyApp[1893:111440] delegate = <MerchantCurrencySyncService: 0x7cbb62f0>
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:23.700 MyApp[1893:111440] <0x7cbb62f0 MerchantCurrencySyncService.m:-[MerchantCurrencySyncService APICall:didReceiveResponse:](57)> Synched default currencies
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:23.707 MyApp[1893:111440] <0x7b645a70 MyAppAPICall.m:-[MyAppAPICall connectionDidFinishLoading:](139)> {
                                                                                                                                                         data =     {
                                                                                                                                                             currencies =         {
                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                             };
                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                         };
                                                                                                                                                         message = OK;
                                                                                                                                                         "response_code" = 200;
                                                                                                                                                     }
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:23.721 MyApp[1893:111440] delegate = <MerchantAccountSettingsSyncService: 0x7ca18490>
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:23.726 MyApp[1893:111440] <0x7ca18490 MerchantAccountSettingsSyncService.m:-[MerchantAccountSettingsSyncService APICall:didReceiveResponse:](171)> Synched merchant account settings currencies
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:23.732 MyApp[1893:111440] <0x7ca10930 MyAppAPICall.m:-[MyAppAPICall connectionDidFinishLoading:](139)> {
                                                                                                                                                         data =     {
                                                                                                                                                             currencies =         {
                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                             };
                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                         };
                                                                                                                                                         message = OK;
                                                                                                                                                         "response_code" = 200;
                                                                                                                                                     }
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:23.774 MyApp[1893:111440] delegate = <MerchantAccountSettingsSyncService: 0x7ca18ec0>
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:23.781 MyApp[1893:111440] <0x7ca18ec0 MerchantAccountSettingsSyncService.m:-[MerchantAccountSettingsSyncService APICall:didReceiveResponse:](171)> Synched merchant account settings currencies
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:23.784 MyApp[1893:111440] <0x7cc47080 MyAppAPICall.m:-[MyAppAPICall connectionDidFinishLoading:](139)> {
                                                                                                                                                         data =     {
                                                                                                                                                             "card_types" =         {
                                                                                                                                                                 0 = master;
                                                                                                                                                                 1 = visa;
                                                                                                                                                             };
                                                                                                                                                             country = "New Zealand";
                                                                                                                                                             currencies =         {
                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                             };
                                                                                                                                                             "default_env_domain" = "wss://emv-nz.MyApp.com";
                                                                                                                                                             "default_system_currency" = NZD;
                                                                                                                                                             "default_time_zone" = "Canada/Central";                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                         };
                                                                                                                                                         message = OK;
                                                                                                                                                         "response_code" = 200;
                                                                                                                                                     }
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:23.785 MyApp[1893:111440] delegate = <MerchantCurrencySyncService: 0x7ca0c970>
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:23.817 MyApp[1893:111440] <0x7ca0c970 MerchantCurrencySyncService.m:-[MerchantCurrencySyncService APICall:didReceiveResponse:](57)> Synched default currencies
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:23.886 MyApp[1893:111440] <0x7cc5cca0 MyAppAPICall.m:-[MyAppAPICall connectionDidFinishLoading:](139)> {
                                                                                                                                                         data =     {
                                                                                                                                                             "last_changed" = "<null>";
                                                                                                                                                         };
                                                                                                                                                         message = OK;
                                                                                                                                                         "response_code" = 200;
                                                                                                                                                     }
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:23.896 MyApp[1893:111440] delegate = <SynchronizeStorefront: 0x7cc5cc40>
                                                                                                                                                     2017-08-08 14:10:40.730 MyApp[1893:111440] Can't find keyplane that supports type 8 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-DecimalPad; using 309711205_Portrait_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                     (lldb)
```

Comment: post your crash log

Comment: What is the type of `chargeAmount`?

Comment: @Malik it is same type NSDecimalNumber

Comment: Can you post your crash log?

Comment: @Malik I am just checking that how to get crash logs :) Any suggestion please?

Comment: Run the code in simulator. When the app crashes, copy the log from console

Comment: @Malik, last messages are pasted below, but seems not relevant.

`2017-08-08 13:26:38.417 SwipeHQC[1660:98143] delegate = <MerchantAccountSettingsSyncService: 0x7876bac0>
2017-08-08 13:26:38.422 SwipeHQC[1660:98143] <0x7876bac0 MerchantAccountSettingsSyncService.m:-[MerchantAccountSettingsSyncService APICall:didReceiveResponse:](171)> Synched merchant account settings currencies
2017-08-08 13:26:41.732 SwipeHQC[1660:98143] Can't find keyplane that supports type 8 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-DecimalPad; using 309711205_Portrait_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default`

Comment: What messages does the Xcode console show?

Comment: This log does not contain any errors. You should update the question with a complete console log.

Comment: @Malik I edited the question with the log.

Comment: @ReinierMelian I have edited the question with logs, please check if you can get any thing from that.

Comment: I cannot see any crash messages in the log. What made you conclude that `cd.amount = chargeAmount` is the issue?

Comment: @Malik after App crash from Xcode simulator, Xcode highlights this line and show EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: Can you share the code where you are initialising the value for `chargeAmount`?

Comment: In the following code.

`if (amount.text.length == 0) {
        chargeAmount = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0"];
    } else {
        chargeAmount = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:amount.text];
    }`